# What is the right configuration to enable cors with nginx and aws?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, cors

I'm migrating my app to an AWS EC2 instance, it used to be hosted in Hostgator and worked fine,  now that I have managed to migrate it I have some problems with a CORS error.

My app is an angular 6 app in the frontend, I deployed it with nginx. The backend is hosted in heroku and its a NodeJs 8.0 Restful API

After many reseach hours I have found that I have to change my app's serve file.

At first it was like this, and it worked well except for the CORS error

```
server {     
 listen 80;      
 listen [::]:80;      
 server_name http://your-site-name.com;      
 root /var/www/app-name;   
 server_tokens off;   
 index index.html index.htm;     

 location / {         
     # First attempt to server request as file, then         
     # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.          
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;      
 }
}
```

Then I tried a solution I found around

```
location / {
  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

     add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
     add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
     add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
     return 204;
  }
  if ($request_method = 'POST') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
 }
  if ($request_method = 'GET') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
  }
}
```

This did not work, and after reloading my page I got a 404 not found nginx error. The next solution did the same:

```
location / {

 # Simple requests
 if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
   add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
 }

 # Preflighted requests
 if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
   add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
   add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
   add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
   return 200;
 }

....
# Handle request
....
```

}

Finally I tried this one:

```
 location / {
     dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;

   # Preflighted requestis
   if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
     add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
     add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE";
     add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    return 200;
  }

  # CORS WHITELIST EVERYTHING
  # This is allowing everything because I am running
  # locally so there should be no security issues.
  if ($request_method = (GET|POST|OPTIONS|HEAD|DELETE)) {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
  }

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
}
```

This last solution worked fine (meaning, my app was loading and no 404 error showed up) BUT still it gave me the CORS error

And yes, I do have enabled CORS in my backend, this is my server.js file:

```
require('./config/config.js');

//Requires
const express = require('express')
const colors = require('colors')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


const app = express();

//Enable cors
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, token");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
 next();
});

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(require("./routes/index"));


//serve
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening ${process.env.PORT}. Status:`, 'online'.green)
});
```

This is the error I'm getting in the browser console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://backend.herokuapp.com/inventory/most_sold' from origin 
'http://front-end-ip' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control- 
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I hope some of you could guide me a little bit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use *CORS*(a node.js package for providing a Connect/Express middleware that can be used to enable CORS with various options) i.e,

- Install *CORS* in node.js by `npm i cors`

In server.js file:-

- `const cors = require("cors");`
- Then set the CORS options,

  `const corsoption = {
    origin: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ["x-auth-token"]
  };`
- `app.use(cors(corsoption));`

Then you will not be blocked by *CORS* policy.

Documentation:- [cors package](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding, unfortunately this solution did not work. As I told you, the backend was working well when it was on Hostgator, no cors errors.That is why I believe it has something to do with the nginx server file. The error is still the same, by the way

Comment: Did you make changes in server.js file and re-host the backend to heroku?!

Comment: Yes I did, and I did it twice just in case

Answer (score 0):

I've had more success using *more_set_headers* on nginx.conf instead of add_header:

```
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.mydomain.test';
    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST';
```

This works even without the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header, both on FF and Chromium.

The *more_set_headers* directive is part of the [HttpHeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module which is included in the [nginx-extras flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553937/what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-full-extras-and-light-packages-for-ngi#556382) of nginx, you can install it on ubuntu 16 using:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-extras